# How to create svn folder in mac os x

Tags: svn, xcode, macos, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am working on iphone project, i like to create an svn folder and link that one to my server
I tried to run the below command

fsp3s-MacBook-Pro:~ fsp3$ svnadmin create /ram/Code/SVN

i got the below error

svnadmin: Repository creation failed
svnadmin: Could not create top-level directory
svnadmin: Can't create directory '/ram/Code/SVN': No such file or directory

How to create an SVN folder in mac os x?

thanks!

Comment: Can you create a normal folder in `/ram/Code/SVN`? I doubt it - it's a Unix filesystem. Doesn't sound like a subversion issue to me.

Answer (score 2):

What that message is telling you is that either /ram/ or /ram/Code don't exist.

But why would you want to create that folder there?

If your user's short name is ram why don't you do `svnadmin create /Users/ram/SVN` ?

But I think you are not asking the right question. I think you want to create a local working copy of a repo on the server, not a local repo.

what you probably need to do is `svn co protocol://server/repo`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, i found the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bash$ mkdir -p /ram/Code
bash$ svnadmin create /ram/Code/SVN
```

`svnadmin` does not create parent directories for you.  It could also be a permissions issue.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, i found the way to fix it.